# Listening for Scheduled Events in a Discord.NET Bot

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I'm converting bots over from javascript and previously I was using `ws` to listen for messages on a socket to be able to schedule events. I'd then use a cron job to run a small script to send a message on that socket on a schedule.

I'm wondering what the equivalent of this would be in C# and Discord.NET. How could I go about this? Any code examples would be appreciated also, trying to find a place to start with this.

Comment: Just to be clear, in your original bot was your workflow that the cron job would send a message over websockets that would then trigger your bot to send a message out to discord?

Comment: @KingOfArrows That's correct yep!